# How to save *.ppt, *.pptx files as *.wmv using Interop with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, powerpoint, wmv

I tried to do this with the next code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

namespace SavePPT
{
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Application app = new PowerPoint.Application();
                var pres = app.Presentations;
                var file = pres.Open(@"C:\Presentation1.pptx", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                file.SaveCopyAs(@"C:\presentation1.wmv", PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV, MsoTriState.msoCTrue);

                app.Quit();

            }
        }
}
```

But this solution created file with 0 KB size and of course I can't play it.

Comment: What kind of app {Command-line, win-forms, web-forms}?  Are you currently running in VStudio (which ver)?  If your OS is Win7, are you doing "run as admin"?

Comment: What version of Office? 2003, for example, doesn't actually have support for ppSaveAsWMV. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220690%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: It's just console application, VS 2010 Ultimate, Win7 run as admin. PowerPoint 2010

Comment: Want to add, that my presentation is not empty, I have there more than 25 slides and it about 241KB in a size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerPoint's SaveCopyAs method doesn't appear to support ppSaveAsWMV. It explicitly states which it supports on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._presentation.savecopyas.aspx) for SaveCopyAs, which doesn't include the ppSaveAsWMV constant.

Comment: Thank you. Can you advice some another solution to convert *.ppt to video format?

Comment: @Blam It's a valid enum. If you see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppsaveasfiletype.aspx it definitely exists, it's just not used by this particular method call. Following traditional .NET practices, it should throw a NotSupportedException, rather than silently failing, but with it being a COM interop they (Microsoft) probably decided that was more hastle than it was worth.

Comment: @AntonKolesnik Use the CreateVideo method instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._presentation.createvideo%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: FYI I've never used any of this stuff. All the answers are in the documentation. You can read the (friendly) manual as much as I can.

Comment: Using VBA from within PPT, both SaveAs or SaveCopyAs work as expected. I wonder if PPT is allowing you to dismiss it while it's still starting to save the WMV.  Try saving a simple 2 or 3 slide presentation this way and introduce 30 seconds or so delay before App.Quit

Answer (score 3):

I find solution:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

namespace SavePPT
{
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string fileName = @"C:\Presentation1.pptx";
                string exportName = "video_of_presentation";
                string exportPath = @"C:\{0}.wmv";

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
                ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                ppApp.WindowState = PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(fileName,
                            MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                try
                {
                    oPres.CreateVideo(exportName);
                    oPres.SaveCopyAs(String.Format(exportPath, exportName),
                        PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV,
                        MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
                }
                finally
                {
                    ppApp.Quit();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This code save file, but with some delay. Thanks for help.

Comment: A delay is expected. The movie file needs to actually be encoded which isn't an instant operation. =)

Comment: hi, i've used your code but i get A first Chance exception at the line 
oPres,createVideo(exportName); might you have forgotten something?Thank you for your time

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Presentation (unknown member) : Failed.'

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
while (oPres.CreateVideoStatus == PpMediaTaskStatus.ppMediaTaskStatusInProgress)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```