# producing .wmv file zero bytes

Tags: c#, powerpoint

Hi guys this is my code in C#,I read a .ppptx file and turn it into a .wmv for some reason it generates a zero size file.When i save it a gif it works ok and i can't find the reason..

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using ppt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

namespace PowerPoint
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //{0} source path filename
        //{1} destination path
        var app = new ppt.Application();

       // ppt.Presentation file = app.Presentations.Open(args[0], MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        ppt.Presentation file = app.Presentations.Open(@"C:\Users\mkolozoff\Desktop\tutorial1.pptx", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

       // file.SaveCopyAs(args[1], PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV);
        file.SaveCopyAs(@"C:\Users\mkolozoff\Desktop\demo.wmv", PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV);

        file.Close();
        app.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(file);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);

        file = null;
        app = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: does `PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV` exist?

Comment: yes it does i saw it for the editor.

Comment: but it's not listed in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746500(v=office.14).aspx and you may want to check this out:http://stackoverflow.com/a/13340305/352101

Comment: Ok this was really helpful thank you very much.I have a problem though.I use remote desktop.When i run the application in the in the server (where i'm connected with remote desktop) everything is ok.When i build the application and copy it to my pc i get an exception.Do you know what could i be doing wrong?thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the `Exception`? Check if you have all the references on your local PC, e.g. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`

Comment: welli think your exactly right i get the exception your suggesting.But i thought that when i builded the program that the referenced libraries should be export it in the .exe (like when external jars are exported to Java)